# SQL Server XML Node Parsing

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

Fairly new to XML parsing in SQL Server. Here's what I have and what I'm trying to do.

I have a table with many rows similar to this:

```
+-------------------+------------------------------------+
| EDI_Assessment_ID |              XML_TEXT              |
+-------------------+------------------------------------+
|             12345 | text column containing XML         |
|             12346 | text column containing XML         |
+-------------------+------------------------------------+
```

The XML_Text column has a large XML text similar to this structure (i've simplified and only pasted the relevant portions of it:

```
<Assessment>
<ADLs>
  <ADL_Group>
     <ADL>bathing</ADL>
     <Mapped_ADL Source="Calypso">Bathing</Mapped_ADL>
     <ADL_Level>Requires only equipment to complete ADL</ADL_Level>
     <Mapped_ADL_Level Source="Calypso">Independent</Mapped_ADL_Level>
     <ADL_Equipment>HH shower</ADL_Equipment>
     <ADL_Assisted_By_Info>
        <ADL_Assisted_By>No one</ADL_Assisted_By>
     </ADL_Assisted_By_Info>
  </ADL_Group>
  <ADL_Group>
     <ADL>Continence-Bowel</ADL>
     <Mapped_ADL Source="Calypso">Continence</Mapped_ADL>
     <ADL_Level>Independent</ADL_Level>
     <Mapped_ADL_Level Source="B/A">Independent</Mapped_ADL_Level>
     <ADL_Equipment />
     <ADL_Assisted_By_Info>
        <ADL_Assisted_By>No one</ADL_Assisted_By>
     </ADL_Assisted_By_Info>
  </ADL_Group>
</Assessment>
```

How can i parse through the XML for each row in the table to return:

1. The ADL (bathing, Continence-Bowel) and
2. the ADL_Assisted_By_Info

I'm looking for the result set to return similar to this:

```
+-------------------+-------------+----------------------+------------------+----------------------+
| EDI_Assessment_ID |   Bathing   | ADL_Assisted_By_Info | Continence-Bowel | ADL_Assisted_By_Info |
+-------------------+-------------+----------------------+------------------+----------------------+
|             12345 | Independent | No one               | Independent      | No one               |
+-------------------+-------------+----------------------+------------------+----------------------+
```

Comment: Out of interest, why are you using `varchar(MAX)` to store xml and not the `xml` datatype? You can't use XQUERY on a `varchar`, so that's automatically making this task harder that it needs to be. if the reason is because the XML isn't valid xml (so, when trying to store it as an `xml` you get an error), then this is far far harder. Ideally you should be fixing the XML first so that it's valid.

Comment: whoops, that's a mistake in my question. it's actually a "text" data type....just FYI, I'm a data analyst so any table design questions I won't be able to answer. I'll edit my question with the correct data type!

Comment: That's even worse, `text` has been deprecated since at least SQL Server 2005. That doesn't answer by question though. Why are you using `varchar(MAX)`/`text`? There's an `xml` datatype and XML should be stored as `xml`.

Comment: No idea...I'm just using what I've been given. Sure sounds like whoever designed this table could have done it better.

Comment: Is changing the data type an option? Otherwise you'll have to `CONVERT` the value of `XML_TEXT` to `xml` every time you want to use XQUERY against it. That's going to slow the query down, as the data engine will have to validate every row you're addressing to ensure it is valid XML.

Comment: Ok, just actually had a look at your XML, and it's not valid (the `ADLs` tag isn't closed); that's basically a show stopper here. If it's not valid, then SQL Server can't help you. You'll need to use something else and do some huge string manipulation.

Comment: Even with valid XML and all that, if you have multiple `ADL_Group`s, you can't dynamically expand these into columns -- T-SQL needs fixed result sets. Do you always need the same two groups or is it dynamic? In the latter case, unless you want to get complicated with dynamic SQL, you're probably better off analyzing things client-side (Excel has some limited but still useful support for shredding XML, for example.) Either that, or change things so you're OK with data being shredded into rows rather than columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These solutions rely on something which, from the OP's sample data is **not** true; that the column of the datatype `text` has **valid** XML. The sample data is not, so this solution will not work against the sample data they have provided.

In fact, if all of the OP's sample data is poorly formed XML then they SQL Server is completely the wrong choice here. They should, ideally, be fixing their data first, and then changing the datatype to `xml` so that more bad XML can't in inserted into the database.

If, for whatever reason, they can't do that then they will need to find a different solution. SQL Server, however, isn't the solution. You're going to need something that is very good as string manipulation and work out the values that way. if you're doing this at a (large) dataset value then the process is probably going to slow down to a crawl.

Anyway, onto the point. Note the comment. There are 2 solution, the first, other than the validity, assumes that the `bathing` node is always the first `ADL_GROUP` element, and that `Continence-Bowel` is always the second:

```
WITH VTE AS(
    SELECT 12345 AS ID,
           CONVERT(text,
'<Assessment>
<ADLs>
  <ADL_Group>
     <ADL>bathing</ADL>
     <Mapped_ADL Source="Calypso">Bathing</Mapped_ADL>
     <ADL_Level>Requires only equipment to complete ADL</ADL_Level>
     <Mapped_ADL_Level Source="Calypso">Independent</Mapped_ADL_Level>
     <ADL_Equipment>HH shower</ADL_Equipment>
     <ADL_Assisted_By_Info>
        <ADL_Assisted_By>No one</ADL_Assisted_By>
     </ADL_Assisted_By_Info>
  </ADL_Group>
  <ADL_Group>
     <ADL>Continence-Bowel</ADL>
     <Mapped_ADL Source="Calypso">Continence</Mapped_ADL>
     <ADL_Level>Independent</ADL_Level>
     <Mapped_ADL_Level Source="B/A">Independent</Mapped_ADL_Level>
     <ADL_Equipment />
     <ADL_Assisted_By_Info>
        <ADL_Assisted_By>No one</ADL_Assisted_By>
     </ADL_Assisted_By_Info>
  </ADL_Group>
</ADLs>' + --I have added this line to make the XML valid. The sample you have will NOT work, as it is not valid XML
'</Assessment>') AS XML_Text
)
SELECT V.ID,
       X.XML_Type,
       T.AA.value('(ADL_Group/Mapped_ADL_Level/text())[1]','varchar(30)') AS Bathing,
       T.AA.value('(ADL_Group/ADL_Assisted_By_Info/ADL_Assisted_By/text())[1]','varchar(30)') AS ADL_Assisted_By_Info,
       T.AA.value('(ADL_Group/Mapped_ADL_Level/text())[2]','varchar(30)') AS ContinenceBowel,
       T.AA.value('(ADL_Group[2]/ADL_Assisted_By_Info/ADL_Assisted_By/text())[1]','varchar(30)') AS ADL_Assisted_By_Info
FROM VTE V
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(TRY_CONVERT(xml, V.XML_Text))) X(XML_Type)
     CROSS APPLY X.XML_Type.nodes('/Assessment/ADLs') T(AA);
```

If, however, that isn't true and there could be other nodes in play, with different values, then you could do the following for the `SELECT` (CTE not included):

```
SELECT V.ID,
       X.XML_Type,
       B.AG.value('(Mapped_ADL_Level/text())[1]','varchar(30)') AS Bathing,
       B.AG.value('(ADL_Assisted_By_Info/ADL_Assisted_By/text())[1]','varchar(30)') AS ADL_Assisted_By_Info,
       CB.AG.value('(Mapped_ADL_Level/text())[1]','varchar(30)') AS ContinenceBowel,
       CB.AG.value('(ADL_Assisted_By_Info/ADL_Assisted_By/text())[1]','varchar(30)') AS ADL_Assisted_By_Info
FROM VTE V
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(TRY_CONVERT(xml, V.XML_Text))) X(XML_Type)
     CROSS APPLY X.XML_Type.nodes('/Assessment/ADLs/ADL_Group') B(AG)
     CROSS APPLY X.XML_Type.nodes('/Assessment/ADLs/ADL_Group') CB(AG)
WHERE B.AG.value('(ADL/text())[1]','varchar(30)') = 'bathing'
  AND CB.AG.value('(ADL/text())[1]','varchar(30)') = 'Continence-Bowel';
```

Comment: Larnu - thank you for taking the time to explain. This is plenty enough to get me up and running (and I'll take your advice to see if the correct persons can change the datatype!)